# Calibration of stock's intrinsic value under the gordon model

Tags: equities, valuation, discounting, present-value

Assume we have the constant growth Gordon model, for a stock paying dividend $D$,Earnings per Share $EPS$, annual growth rate $g=ROE*(1-\frac{D}{EPS})$ and discount rate $r$. 
Then:

$IV=\frac{D*(1+g)}{r-g}$. In this particular case, we consider that dividends are being paid 1 year from now. My though on this:

Assume that last dividend was paid yesterday, annual payments. Then today:
$IV_0=\frac{D*(1+g)}{r-g}$
Tommorow:
$IV_1=IV_0*(1+\frac{r}{365})$ in 2 days, 
$IV_2=IV_1*(1+\frac{r}{365})$ ...

Is the a better method of estimating daily IV, adjusting to a different discount rate?